# start a python script as soon as power is supplied

Tags: linux, ssh, raspberry-pi, startup

I work on raspberry pi via SSH session, model B raspbian 
I want the  python script to run as soon as I plug in the power supply to my raspberry pi without connecting the ethernet cable.

I have found people asking about starting the script on boot up and what I found is to add the command in rc.local so I did
it looks like that now

```
    #!/bin/sh -e
#
# rc.local
#
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
# Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
# value on error.
#
# In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
# bits.
#
# By default this script does nothing.

# Print the IP address
_IP=$(hostname -I) || true
if [ "$_IP" ]; then
  printf "My IP address is %s\n" "$_IP"
fi
sudo python tt3.py  --cascade=s.xml 0 
exit 0
```

but it doest work neither on plug in power supply or on starting up the SSH session

Comment: there is a dedicated stack exchange size for raspberry pi: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

I think you are headed in the correct direction, but the issue probably revolves around tt3.py and s.xml not being found where rc.local is being run (its `cwd` - current working dir).

Try making the paths to the files explicit. Also check out `/var/log/messages` to see if there are any applicable error messages relevant to your script.

Also remember, rc.local is just another file which can be executed. So to test out if this will work, you can always run ./rc.local from its directory.

Comment: executing the rc.local file alone does the job perfectly but not when I plug in the power supply nor when I lunch the SSH session (lxsession)

Comment: Do you see any warning signs in `/var/log/messages` related to your app? What is the path to tt3 and s.xml?